# using Bootstrap-Progressbar.js to dynamically render progress bars in a Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use Bootstrap-Progressbar.js  https://github.com/minddust/bootstrap-progressbar  to dynamically render a progressbar based upon a user's percentage complete (of an event). I calculate the VALUE in the users controller:

```
# Calculate percentage complete
  if @hours_total <= 120
    @hours_total_raw = @hours_total                            
    @hours_total_percentage = (@hours_total).to_f/120.to_f.round(0)
  else @hours_total >= 121
    @hours_total_raw = 120
    @hours_total_percentage = 100
  end
```

In the user's status page, I have the Bootstrap progressbar code (as shown by Minddust, above):

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow = "VALUE"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, Minddust says to replace aria-valuenow with data-transitionsgoal.  Unfortunately, that "bricked" my progressbar (in Chrome on a Mac) to use Minddust's term, so I reverted to aria-valuenow.

The VALUE is passed TO - not from - the following javascript to render the progressbar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".progress .progress-bar-success").progressbar({
});
```

This is the basic functionality show in Minddust's demos.  The progressbar correctly renders as a percentage of 100% whatever number I manually make VALUE.  How do I pass a number to VALUE - which is inside the div brackets < div ... aria-valuenow = "VALUE"  >.  "VALUE" is an instance variable that has not been saved to the database; it is calculated on the fly.

The answers I found on Stackoverflow, e.g., the excellent answer to question # 21182058 (passing a pre-defined value from a checkbox), all recommend using javascript; however, they all deal with situations where one is passing in a value from html and not dynamically changing that value.

I've tried a variety of approaches, even passing the value as "data" attached to the link that re-directs the user to the status page with no luck.  Is what I want to do even feasible?  Is there a gem - or different approach all together - that will accomplish this?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works.
HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="
      <%= @hours_total_percentage %>" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 
      <%= @hours_total_percentage %>%;"><span style="text-align: center;">
      <%= @hours_total_percentage %>%</span>
    </div>     
  </div>
```

Javascript - code with default options from Minddust (as above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".progress .progress-bar-success").progressbar({
    transition_delay: 0,
    refresh_speed: 0,
    display_text: 'center',
    use_percentage: true,
    percent_format: function(percent) { return percent + '%'; },
    amount_format: function(amount_part, amount_total) { return amount_part + ' / ' + 
    amount_total; },
    update: $.noop,
    done: $.noop,
    fail: $.noop
  });
});
```

For the record, I'm not quite sure what wasn't working before.  I had tried this approach and it didn't work.  Maybe adding the default values to the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can set some property of progress bar.

```
var value = 55;// make call to get value from server.
var $progressBar = $('.progress .progress-bar');
$progressBar.css('width', value + '%');
$progressBar.attr('aria-valuenow', value + '%');
$progressBar.html(value + '%');
```